# JAXB-WS: XmlElement and WebParam

Tags: java, soap, jaxb, wsdl

I'm trying to make a web method parameter required. I'm using JAXB2.2, so I can use the XmlElement annotation on params. The problem is that in the generated wsdl I can still have minOccurs=0.

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "retrieve")
@WebResult(name = "response")
public RetrieveWrapper retrieve(@WebParam(name = "name") @XmlElement(nillable=false, required=true) String name) {
```

And in the generated wsdl I have this:

```
<xs:complexType name="retrieve">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" type="ns1:String" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Any advice please? What I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

The "name" in your complexType "retrieve" is optional.
You probably have a Class that corresponds to "retrieve" with a field "name" on which you didn't define "required=true". But that's not what you want.

I think your wsdl is correct for what you want, check your wsdl you should have and other element "name" which corresponds to your webparam and is required (no "minoccurs").

Comment: Hello, thanks for the advice, I tried it and still didn't get the outcome I'm expecting: `@WebMethod
    @WebResult(name = "response")
    public RetrieveWrapper retrieve(@WebParam @XmlElement(nillable = false, required = true) String name)` and the generate wsdl id: `<xs:complexType name="retrieve">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="arg0" type="ns1:user" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>`. I want to mention that I commented out everything else from the class.